# Get data via Netatmo API within R

Tags: r, api, oauth, access-token

I tried to get data from a netatmo station I have access to via API. The following code I used in R.

```
myapp   <- oauth_app("my_netatmo",key="my_netatmo_client_id",secret="my_netatmo_client_secret")
ep      <- oauth_endpoint(authorize = "http://api.netatmo.net/oauth2/authorize",access = "http://api.netatmo.net/oauth2/token")
sig_tok <- oauth2.0_token(ep,myapp, scope="read_station")

#after that I get redirected to my browser to log in and after that sig_tok contains an access token
sig     <- config(token = sig_tok)
html_get<-GET("http://api.netatmo.net/api/devicelist",sig)
```

html_get contains this:

```
html_get
Response [http://api.netatmo.net/api/devicelist]
    Status: 400
    Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    {"error":{"code":1,"message":"Access token is missing"}}
```

What am I doing wrong since "sig" seems to contain a token:

```
sig$token$credentials$access_token
[1] "5**********************f|3**********************a"
```

There are two tokens or am I wrong (because of "|" in between)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '|' inside the access_token is part of it, it is only one access token.

From the documentation: http://dev.netatmo.com/doc/methods/devicelist,
the parameter name is: "access_token". I don't know the R language, but it seems you are sending "token" as a parameter, and not "access_token". It may explain the issue.

Comment: Hi Fabien, thanx for the answer so I could be more focused on the program language I used and found out that I have to construct the url "by hand" instead of using the func config: json_get<-GET(paste("http://api.netatmo.net/api/devicelist?access_token=", sig_tok$credentials$access_token,sep = "")) Now it work! PS: The response is in a jason format not html